# How do I add leading zero to a 7 digit date using When clause in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a column of dates, which have some 7 digits and 8 digit characters as type string.

```
  dates_stamp
  9022023
  10012023
  14012023
  4122022
```

How do I add a leading zero to dates?

```
select CASE
        WHEN last_contact_date BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999
        THEN ('0' , CAST(last_contact_date  as VARCHAR(8)))
        ELSE "FAIL"
         END
FROM table1
```

This is my concept but not sure how to make it work

Comment: Perhaps something like this    right(concat('00000000',dates_stamp),8)  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/6_OM7_tE

Comment: Sorry its `else  CAST(last_contact_date AS VARCHAR(8)` not fail

Comment: Honestly, why not store the date as a `date`, and worry about the format it's presented in in the presentation layer? Your column will be a nightmare to work with if you dates before or after another date; according to your data 2023-01-10 (`10012023`) is **before** 2022-12-04 (`4122022`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String functions in Amazon Athena are based on [Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html).  It contains an `lpad` function that should suit your needs.

```
lpad(Cast(last_contact_date as VarChar(8), last_contact_date, 8, '0')
```

I would strongly suggest complying with the ISO 8601 international standard. `"YYYY-MM-DD"` retains a way to sort after conversion to string.

```
substring(to_iso8601(last_contact_date),1,10)
```